# How to open path directory in Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

I'm a newbie to OSX.
I have installed android studio and created an test project.
I would like to open up the test project directory as what I can do in Windows.
Here is the path to the test project directory:
/Users/wenhao/AndroidStudioProjects

But I have no idea where to navigate the /Users directory.

Appreciate if someone can help me out.

--- EDIT ---
I recalled that I have accidentally deleted something from the finder.
So, in order for those section to show: please follow this post - http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/193314-accidentally-removed-device-finder-sidebar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Finder, you should have on the left side "Devices" section, and under that, "Macintosh HD". From there, you should be able to find the path you are looking for.

Alternately, you could open Terminal app (in the Utilities folder of your Applications); that should put you in the `/Users/wenhao` directory, where you can just issue the command `open AndroidStudioProjects` to show it in Finder.